# XCode - FB URL Schemes Not Working

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook-graph-api, ios7, facebook-ios-sdk

I have the following code in my iOS app, attempting to open up a user's Facebook page in the app:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"fb://profile/%@",fbidStr]];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];

    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url]){
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
    }

    else {
      [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.facebook.com/%@",fbidStr]]];
    }
```

When the app opens, I get an error 'The page you requested was not found'. I've NSLogged the URL and it looks fine:

fb://profile/10154531xxxxx65245

And everything works fine when the user doesn't have the app installed and views the profile in safari.

What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I've had the some problem, it seems that Facebook only accepts on their profile module people that are already friends with you.